# Is it possible to exit a (native) function from inside the callback that that function takes?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to exit a (native) function from inside the callback that that function takes?

For example, I only want the first callback, that logs `1`, to execute.

```js
a = [1, 2, 3];

a.forEach(function (element) {
    console.log(element);
    return; 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the function. In the specific case of `forEach` the answer is no. This is explained on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by
> throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method
> is the wrong tool.
>
> Early termination may be accomplished with:
>
> - A simple for loop
> - A for...of / for...in loops
> - Array.prototype.every()
> - Array.prototype.some()
> - Array.prototype.find()
> - Array.prototype.findIndex()
>
> Array methods: every(), some(), find(), and findIndex() test the array
> elements with a predicate returning a truthy value to determine if
> further iteration is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it using `forEach()` you could check `element` against a target number (in this case, `x`) and if it meets the condition, quit the loop rather than execute.

```js
a = [1, 2, 3];
x = 1; // target number

a.forEach(function(element) {
  if (element > x) { // check if element is greater than the target number
    return; // if so, exit the function
  }
  console.log(element);
  return;
});
```